# Al intentar convertir una imagen ARW a JPG me sale el error : TIFF directory is missing required "ImageLength" field

Tags: php, conversión-de-tipos, imagemagick

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $numeroPersona = $_POST['numero'];
    $numeroExtension = strval($numeroPersona . '.jpg');
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ftmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $ferr = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $check = explode(".", $fname);
    $ext = end($check);
    // $ftmp = TIFFOpen($ftmp[0]);
    if (!$ftmp) {
   
?>
        <html>
        <script>
            alert("ERROR: Please select a file first!");
            location.href = '/Image/1.html';
        </script>

        </html>
    <?php
    } else if (!preg_match("/\.(tiff64|tiff|cr2|pef|nef|dng|arw|png|raw)$/i", $fname)) {
        
    ?>
        <html>
        <script>
            alert("ERROR: File is not in TIF,TIFF,CR2,PEF,NEF or DNG");
            location.href = '/Image/1.html';
        </script>

        </html>
    <?php
    } else {
        
    ?>
        <html>
        <script>
            alert("File uploaded <?php echo $numeroExtension; ?>");
        </script>

        </html>
        <?php
        
        $im = new Imagick($ftmp);
        $im->thumbnailImage(360, 480, true, true);
        $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
       
        file_put_contents($numeroExtension, $im); 
        ?>
        <html>
        <script>
            function ok() {
                location.href = '/Image/1.html';
            }
        </script>
        <img src="<?php echo $numeroExtension ?>" height="480" width="360">
        <input type="Button" Value="Done" onclick="ok()">

        </html>
<?php
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();
    }
} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Convertidor</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align=center>Upload image</h1>
    <form action='index.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <p>Please select the file:</p><br>
        <input type="file" name="file"><br>
        <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="number" name="numero" id="">
        <input type="Reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Estoy intentando hacer un convertidor con PHP y la libreria ImageMagick, pero al intentar convertir imagenes de tipo ARW O CR2 u otros fromatos de camara a JPG me aparece el error:  TIFF directory is missing required "ImageLength" field. Muestro el codigo, normalmente el error me sale en la linea 50. Al intentar crear la variable con ImageMagick. He intentado buscar información sobre el probela pero no encuentro el por qué, ya le guarde el Dll en el php.ini y demas cosas que en la instalación se deben hacer

Comment: ¿TIenes alguna imagen de prueba para revisar?

Comment: ¿De qué necesitas la imagen? ¿Del codigo? Lo siento, tu pregunta me ha sido ambigua...

Comment: "al intentar convertir imagenes de tipo ...". ¿Tienes alguna imagen para probar? ¿Cómo estás llamando a ImageMagick (parámetros)? La idea es poder bajar la imagen y ejecutar ImageMagick a mano, a ver que sale.}

Comment: Ya puedes ver el codigo. esta algo desodenado pero quiero hallar primero la forma de hacer la conversión. Ya luego pienso estructurarlo mejor.

Comment: Qué versión de PHP y de ImageMagick intentas usar? Tiene pinta de que estás usando un código "reciente" y un OS / PHP vieeeejo (al menos de 2015)

Comment: En php estoy usando la versión 7.4.16 y de imageMagick la versión de modulo 3.5.1, sin embargo yo había descargado la versión 7.1.0-11Q16-HDRI-X64-dll.exe.